# Get links inside a DIV

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I want to be able to get first link from inside this div.

```
    <div id="first-tweet-wrapper">
    <blockquote class="tweet" lang="en">
    <a href="htttp://link.com">                          <--- This one
      text    </a>
  </blockquote>
  <a href="http://link2.net" class="click-tracking" target="_blank"
     data-tracking-category="discover" data-tracking-action="tweet-the-tweet">
    Tweet it!  </a>
</div>
```

I've tried with this code but it doesn't work

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);

var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='first-tweet-wrapper']");
if (div != null)
{
      var links = div.Descendants("a")
          .Select(a => a.InnerText)
          .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the **value** of the **href-attribute** of the [anchor element](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) using HtmlAgilityPack's **GetAttributeValue** method. You could access the single anchor element by extracting directly the content of the parent blockcode element like this:

> //div[@id='first-tweet-wrapper']/blockquote[@class='twitter-tweet']

Then fetch the single link inside. A possible solution could look like this (in this case the input is *facebook*, but works with *microsoft* too):

```
try
{           
    // download the html source
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var source = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://discover.twitter.com/first-tweet?username=facebook#facebook");
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(source);

    var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='first-tweet-wrapper']/blockquote[@class='twitter-tweet']");
    if (div != null)
    {
        // there is only one links
        var link = div.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
        if (link != null)
        {
            // take the value of the attribute
            var href = link.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
            Console.WriteLine(href);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

The output is in this case:

> https://twitter.com/facebook/statuses/936094700

Another possibility is to directly select the anchor element using XPath (like @har07 suggested):

```
    var xpath = @"//div[@id='first-tweet-wrapper']/blockquote[@class='twitter-tweet']/a";
    var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    if (link != null)
    {
        // take the value of the href-attribute
        var href = link.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
        Console.WriteLine(href);
    }
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: It works with the HTML code portion from your example. Where do you receive your input from? Can you paste the url or a complete HTML page? It could be, that your input has more than one div with a link in it.

Comment: I added a check to avoid empty results. Can you give the complete page code in your question?

Comment: The html I posted, is a part of this page https://discover.twitter.com/first-tweet#Microsoft. I need to get the link of the tweet

Comment: I changed my answer to download the page and extract the link

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `<div>` id is "first-tweet-wrapper" instead of "firt", you can use this XPath query to get `<a>` element inside `<blockquote>` :

```
//div[@id='first-tweet-wrapper']/blockquote/a
```

So your code will look about like this :

```
var a = doc.DocumentNode
             .SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='first-tweet-wrapper']/blockquote/a");
if (a != null)
{
      var text = a.InnerText;
      var link = a.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
}
```

Comment: Tried but "a" is null

Comment: given the html/xml is exactly as posted, this should work (tested). Post the actual xml if you didn't test with the one in this question.

Comment: The html I posted, is a part of this page https://discover.twitter.com/first-tweet#Microsoft. I need to get the link of the tweet